# Python: Nexcord.UI I don't know how it's passing arguments to the method when I'm passing the arguments to a class

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

The terminal is telling me I'm passing 3 arguments to a method/function and I'm a little lost how that is happening or why. It's a button interface and when the user clicks the button, I get this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\nextcord\ui\view.py", line 359, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
TypeError: MatchComplete.rematch_button() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have only been messing in this class and haven't changed anything else, when I added the user checks in the code and another button, it stopped working.
here is my relevant code,

```
#bug here
await interaction.response.edit_message(content = "<@{}> Wins Against <@{}>!".format(winner.get_id(), loser.get_id()), view=MatchComplete(self.p1, self.p2, self.battle_thread))

#the class
class MatchComplete(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, p1=None, p2=None, battle_thread = None):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.battle_thread = battle_thread

    async def interaction_check1(player_to_check, interaction):
        return player_to_check == interaction.user      
    
    @nextcord.ui.button(label= "REMATCH",emoji="<:Cutedragon:794999307048321044>", style= nextcord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id= "rematch01")
    async def rematch_button(self, interaction):
        
        if await self.interaction_check1(self.p2, interaction) or await self.interaction_check1(self.p1, interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message(content = "lets go", view = WinorLose(self.p1, self.p2, self.battle_thread))
    
    @nextcord.ui.button(label= "END WAR",emoji="<:Cutedragon:794999307048321044>", style= nextcord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id= "endMatch01")
    async def endMatch_button(self, interaction):        
        
        if await self.interaction_check1(self.p2, interaction) or await self.interaction_check1(self.p1, interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message(content ="Goodbye", view = self)
```

Comment: Try updating the module by `pip install nextcord -U`. It may be a bug